# Get src img with Powershell Where-Object

Tags: jquery, html, css, powershell

I have an html sample like this. I want to get img src link. How to get it with using Powershell?

```
<ul class="filtered similiar">
                 <li class="one pie lcls">
                    <div class="productImg">
                       <a href="/sihirli-kirmizi-at2612">
<img src="https://sample.jpg" width="170" height="238" alt="Kırmızı Gül Çiçek Aranjmanı" title="Kırmızı Gül Çiçek Aranjmanı">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                 </li>
```

Comment: Is there anything you tried. The _could_ be straightforward. Solutions could be dependent on your PowerShell version.

Comment: Glad to see you are using a preferred approach for parsing html. Add that to your question. The community can test with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple example, use this:

```
$html = '<img src="https://sample.jpg" width="170" height="238" alt="Kırmızı Gül Çiçek Aranjmanı" title="Kırmızı Gül Çiçek Aranjmanı">'

$srcrpattern = '(?i)src="(.*?)"'

$src = ([regex]$srcrpattern ).Matches($html) |  ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value }
```

Tested it quickly with your full HTML and it works fine also. Hope that helps.